# Using .max() with .stream() on a List<>

Tags: java, list, java-8, max, java-stream

I would like to ask for an explanation to some code that I was given as a solution to an exercise I am doing in a Java course.
The exercise is I have a `List<>`of Employees with various properties(Salary, Name, Surname, E-mail...) and I am trying to retrieve the highest paid employee and print their Name and Salary.

I was able to retrieve the highest Salary but not the Name of the employee, like this:

```
Integer maxSalary;
maxSalary = roster
    .stream()
    .map(Employee :: getSalary)
    .collect(Collectors.reducing(Integer :: max)
    .get();
```

I was then given this small block of code and it works completely fine yet i am not quite sure why it works:

```
Integer maxSalary;
Employee emp2 = roster
    .stream()
    .max((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.getSalary(), p2.getSalary()))
    .get();
System.out.println("The employee who earns the most is :" + emp2.getName + " and earns : " + emp2.getSalary + " a month.");
```

I understand it is a Lambda expression using `.max` i just cant seem to get my head around why and how it works?

Comment: grabs the list into a stream (hides looping thru it from you), and gets the `max()` - it does so by comparing element `p1` with element `p2`, each is the next and previous item in the list (while going thru it) and does a comparison of those two items. The result of the comparison (between two numbers) is passed to the next step (becomes previous item in the next comparison) and is evaluated with the next element in the list.  Again looping is hidden from you

Comment: that invisible looping was what was doing my head in, i had thought of it but couldn't seem to find anything suggesting as such. Thanks all.

Comment: I'd replace the comparison line with: max(Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getSalary))

Comment: Don't use `get()` unconditionally -- if the stream is empty, it will throw.  Use one of the safe `Optional` methods -- `orElse()`, `orElseThrow()`, etc, that deals with the problem of empty streams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Optional<T> max(Comparator<? super T> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) explains it all.

Since intent of the question was to find the employee with the highest salary, stream is passed directly to `.max` which consumes an employee `comparator`. Since `comparator` is functional interface, it can be passed in as lambda.
`.max` is already implemented version of more general `reduce` and `collect` operation available since java 8

[`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) compares two int numerically. Therefore the `.max()` returns the employee with the highest salary.

On the other hand your attempt is specifically trying to get the highest salary.

Cheers. Happy streaming.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Stream#max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) function:

> Returns the maximum element of this stream according to the provided Comparator. This is a special case of a reduction.

As [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is a functional interface with only `compare(T o1, T o2)` to implement, it may be represented with a lambda. Here, the lambda `(p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.getSalary(), p2.getSalary())` compares the salary of `p1` with the salary of `p2` using standard integer comparison. Therefore, the result will be the `Employee` with the largest salary.

Answer (score 2):

`max` takes a function it uses to compare elements,

```
(p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.getSalary(), p2.getSalary())
```

is a lambda - it's used to compare salary information from every element to find the greatest value.

Answer (score 2):

```
Optional<T> max(Comparator<? super T> comparator);
```

> Returns the maximum element of this stream according to the provided
>   Comparator. This is a special case of a reduction.

`Comparator` is a functional interface that allows to specify an order on a collection of objects of a specific type.

Here is the functional interface method :

```
int compare(T o1, T o2);
```

So, when `max()` is invoked, you can pass to it a lambda that has as argument two `Employee` as the type of the Stream is `Employee` and provide a comparison implementation of two `Employee` objects as  `int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2)` expects to :

```
.max((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.getSalary(), p2.getSalary()))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple: in your solution you convert Employees to their salaries and then find max number among numbers. In the second (and correct) solution you don't perform any conversion: you compare Employees themselves **by particular criteria**. And the criteria in your case is the salary. So eventually `max()` gets not the max number, but the 'max employee' (by the salary).